# Loading csv with pandas, wrong columns

Tags: pandas, csv, format

I loaded a csv into a DataFrame  with pandas.

The format is the following:

```
Timestamp | 1014.temperature | 1014.humidity | 1015.temperature | 1015.humidity ....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-...  | 23.12            | 12.2          |  25.10           | 10.34         .....
```

The problem is that the '1014' or '1015' numbers are supposed to be ID's that are supposed to be in a special column.

I would like to end up with the following format for my DF:

```
TimeStamp | ID       | Temperature | Humidity
-----------------------------------------------
.         |          |             |
.
.
.
```

The CSV is tab separated.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It is better to load the csv that way and then do this transformation you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
# create sample data frame
s = """Timestamp|1014.temperature|1014.humidity|1015.temperature|1015.humidity
2017|23.12|12.2|25.10|10.34"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|')
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

# split columns on '.' with list comprehension
l = [col.split('.') for col in df.columns]
# create multi index columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)
# stack column level 0, reset the index and rename level_1
final = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'ID'})

   Timestamp    ID  humidity  temperature
0       2017  1014     12.20        23.12
1       2017  1015     10.34        25.10
```